# CSS3 background-size

Tags: css

Is there a way of switching between CSS classes without using JS? Just HTML with CSS.

I would like to be able to switch between these two classes

```
.b1 { background-size: cover }
.b2 { background-size: 100% }
```

Possible?

Comment: ... short answer, no. what is your intent, provide more detail ...

Comment: No.  To do so would require the HTML element to change it's class from .b1 to .b2.  CSS can't modify HTML code directly like that.  You need javascript to do this.  In any case, the javascript needed to do this is rather minimal.

Comment: How would you expect it to "switch" between those two classes anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is not possible.**

You can only change the CSS properties on an element based on certain events, such as `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus`, etc.

Learn more about what you can do with CSS pseudo elements here: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/